# Spring Cloud Task - Support Multiple Application Contexts

Tags: spring-cloud-task

It appears that Spring Cloud Task lifecycle is incorrectly managed when spring boot application has hierarchical application contexts.

When i add @EnableTask annotation to the parent ApplicationContext, it registers the task, but records execution time from the parent context, failing to record accurate execution time and exit code (always success as parent context closes successfuly).

On the other hand, if i add annotation to the child context (which actually runs CommandlineRunner), it fails to start the task at all with below exception:

```
o.s.c.t.listener.TaskLifecycleListener : [] [] An event to end a task has been received for a task that has not yet started.
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : [] [] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 132515 not found
```

Looking at the TaskLifecycleListener source, it appears that it reacts to ApplicationEvents from parent context and catches ApplicationReadyEvent from parent context before the task is started.

Spring Boot 2.2.6 / Spring Cloud Task 2.2.2

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.  The "task" is registered as a single execution of a Boot application, not the execution of an `ApplicationContext`.  In a microservices world, you would want to break up your tasks into independent artifacts, therefore running them as independent Spring Boot applications.  There is no support for Spring Cloud Task to support multiple "task" executions within a single Spring Boot application as that goes against what its intent is.  If you feel this is something that should be added, feel free to open up an issue on Github where we can explore your use case deeper.

Comment: My app is a single task app with no WEB, but it has hierarchical contexts because I need to configure the same service in different ways depending on region.  So I have multiple identical regional service beans configured differently each in its own context which I then delegate to during task execution (leaving in another context).

Comment: That doesn't change the end result...one task equals one execution of the application.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. The issue was that task auto configuration was kicking in for parent and child contexts twice. As you say, it is supposed to autoconfigure just once per application and when I addressed this, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I realized what happens is that Spring auto configures task in my main parent context which closes the task.  And same appears to be happening in my child context.  Since executionId is passed as parameter, it is already updated by the parent as executed, so it fails in my child context.

Solution I found to this was to exclude autoconfiguration of SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration from my parent context.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Instead I manually import configuration class in my child context which executes the task:

```
@EnableTask
@Import(SimpleTaskAutoConfiguration.class)
```

That now tracks actual time it took to execute the command line runner as a task within child context, although it doesn't account for time of running whole app, at least it reflects more accurate picture.